# jQuery Select box (roblaplaca) with custom scroll bar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have used http://www.roblaplaca.com/docs/custom-selectbox/ for custom select box script and I have used two select box, second select box updating **using AJAX** on change event for first select box. Below is sample HTML.

```
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
```

I have used sync() method for updating my select box after AJAX success, content is also get updated but problem is **scroll bar disappears**

I have checked sync() method in **selectbox.js** file it calls **_setupScrollbar();** method after content update but whey scroll bar is not appearing any help on this?

You can check [Demo code](http://demo1.zylone.com/jQuery-Custom-Selectbox-master/)

Comment: Create a fiddle please

Comment: I have tried with jsFiddle but script is not working so I have put this sample code on my server... Will you please help me to create fiddle from demo code.

Comment: sure. Show me your code

Comment: You can check from http://demo1.zylone.com/jQuery-Custom-Selectbox-master/

Comment: @SarathSprakash any good luck.....?

Comment: I think its a problem with the plugin

Comment: Ya i am alos facing this issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **SelectBox.js** you will need to modify following codes

(1) Find this `function _setupScrollbar()` and add this code `autoReinitialise: true`. Code will be show look like this.

```
self.scrollpane = $dl.jScrollPane($.extend({
    contentWidth: 200,
    autoReinitialise: true
}, cfg.scrollOptions));
```

(2) Find this function `this.sync = function()` and change code like bellow.

```
this.sync = function() {
    $options = cfg.selectbox.find("option");
    //$dl.html(_renderOptions());
    $jpane = $customSelect.find("div.jspPane");

    if($jpane.length == 1) // need to check if selectbox having scroll bar?
    {
       $jpane.html(_renderOptions()); //HTML injected to selectbox having scrollbar
    }
    else
    {
       $dl.html(_renderOptions()); //else HTML injected to selectbox not having scrollbar
    }

    _bindHover();
    _setupScrollbar();
};
```

Scrollbar is not working because of your jsPane get replaced with new content, so I have changed following code in sync();

```
// $dl.html(_renderOptions());
$jpane = $customSelect.find("div.jspPane");
if($jpane.length == 1) // need to check if selectbox having scroll bar?
{
   $jpane.html(_renderOptions()); //HTML injected to selectbox having scrollbar
}
else
{
   $dl.html(_renderOptions()); //else HTML injected to selectbox not having scrollbar
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help it did the trick... :) I have updated my demo code http://demo1.zylone.com/jQuery-Custom-Selectbox-master/

Answer (score 0):

I have modified @rajnikanth code in following for selectbox which does not having scroll bar

```
this.sync = function() {
    $options = cfg.selectbox.find("option");
    //$dl.html(_renderOptions());
    $jpane = $customSelect.find("div.jspPane");

    if($jpane.length == 1) // need to check if selectbox having scroll bar?
    {
       $jpane.html(_renderOptions()); //HTML injected to selectbox having scrollbar
    }
    else
    {
       $dl.html(_renderOptions()); //else HTML injected to selectbox not having scrollbar
    }

    _bindHover();
    _setupScrollbar();
};
```