# Can't get jScrollPane plus SelectBox plugins to work together

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane, jquery-selectbox

Ok, I have two plugins I am using, one that helps make fancy select box dropdowns - works fine. Plugin: [jQuery Selectbox plugin](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/)

Then I have one so I can make a custom scroll on elements, that works fine too. Plugin: [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)

However I cannot get them working together - a dropdown menu with a custom scroll.

You can see here working examples: http://jsfiddle.net/8VX4d/23/

The first box is a box without scroll (correct), the second is a working box with a scroll correctly working and the one below is a dropdown that I am trying to get the custom scroll working on but can't.

Not sure if it has anything to do with the selectbox instance having to be ready before I apply the custom scroll and I'm not sure how I can check if it is?

As you can see on jsFiddle I am using onDomReady and binding them via:

```
//$(".pretty_sb").selectbox();
$('.cat_list').jScrollPane();
$(".pretty_sb").selectbox();
$('.sbOptions').jScrollPane();
//$('.sbHolder').jScrollPane();
```

**Edit:**

This seems to work but for some reason it restricts the height it shows for the dropdown:

```
$(".pretty_sb").selectbox({
    onOpen: function (inst) {
        $('.sbOptions').jScrollPane({
            verticalDragMinHeight: 40
        });
    }
});
//$('.sbOptions').jScrollPane();
$('.cat_list').jScrollPane();
```

**Edit #2:** I have a `min-height` set for the `sbOptions` class and that is the height that jScrollPane seems to be taking for some reason!?

Comment: The jQuery Selectbox plugin is throwing an error in the jsfiddle. It's using the deprecated `live()` function. Is the jQuery library supposed to be 1.7.2 in the fiddle?

Comment: No, it's supposed to be 1.10.1; I have added `jquery migrate` to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 0 - Reinitialize and Destroy

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8VX4d/39/

```
$('.pretty_sb').selectbox({
    onOpen: function (inst) {
        var api = $('.sbOptions').data('jsp');
        api.reinitialise({
            autoReinitialise: true,
            autoReinitialiseDelay: 10,
        });
    },
    onClose: function (inst) {
        var api = $('.sbOptions').data('jsp');
        api.destroy();
        $('.sbOptions').jScrollPane();
    }
});
$('.sbOptions').jScrollPane();
```

Tested on:

- Chrome v 31.0.1650.63 m
- FireFox 26.0
- IE10

### Solution 1 - Reinitialize on a Delay

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8VX4d/36/

The following will force a reinitialization of the scroll pane which corrects the height. However, this requires a lot of overhead. The end goal would be to manually reinitialize as described in [jScrollPane - dynamic content demo page](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_content.html).

```
$('.pretty_sb').selectbox({
    onOpen: function (inst) {
        $('.sbOptions').jScrollPane({
            autoReinitialise: true,
            autoReinitialiseDelay: 10,
        });
    }
});
```

### Solution 2 - Explicitly Set Height

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8VX4d/29/

The following appears to produce the desired result. I got the idea of forcing the height before applying the jScrollPane [from this blog post](http://offshootinc.com/blog/2010/03/02/jquery-jscrollpane-plugin-scrolling-divs-not-displaying-properly/).

```
$(".pretty_sb").selectbox({
    onOpen: function (inst) {
        $('.sbOptions').height(300).jScrollPane();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but setting a height is not something I wanted to do as it will be applied to many different fields, some dynamic.

Comment: @Brett Understood. Added another solution that should work across different fields as it doesn't explicitly set the height.

Comment: Hmmm I tried that out but it showed some strange behavior; started out as custom scroll but then turned to the default scroll and did some other weird stuff as well.

Comment: @Brett I added another solution that shouldn't present the issues you were seeing.

Comment: Are you sure that works? I tested it but when I opened it all I saw was the default scroll bar.

Comment: [Isn't this basically what you're after?](http://phprocks.letsnurture.com/custom-selectbox-with-custom-scrollbar-using-jquery-plugin-rob-la-placa/) [It's based on this SO answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952286/jquery-select-box-roblaplaca-with-custom-scroll-bar-not-working/18955005#18955005) I'm going to try an implement it now.

Comment: Pretty much yeah, but that uses a different plugin for the selectbox. Was hoping to get it working with the one I'm using. If not, then I guess I will have to go with setting varying heights or something.

Comment: [Here's the best I've been able to accomplish with the reinitialization](http://jsfiddle.net/8VX4d/39/). Let me know if that looks better. My original tests were on Chrome on OS X which looks better than Chrome on Win 7.

Comment: That actually seems to work pretty well now - I'm happy with that! :)

Comment: Sorry for the numerous replies and posts. The solution could probably still be improved upon. At least the height doesn't need to be set explicitly and the reinitialize isn't called repeatedly. Glad I could help.

Comment: No problems. Appreciate the help. One last question - does the code have to be wrapped in a function block like that? ..or is that not really needed?

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I tried that code on the site and it wouldn't execute whilst it was wrapped in the anonymous function, removed it, it worked but didn't show any scroll bars.

Comment: [It appears to not require the anonymous function.](http://jsfiddle.net/8VX4d/41/) However, the jQuery version I set the code to in the fiddle is 1.8.3 due to the `live` error I mentioned in the comments previously. Versions greater than 1.8.3 seem to break the scrollbar. If jQuery version 10 is required, I'll perform some testing to see if I can get that to work.

Comment: Hmmmm...... scroll bar works fine on my site with jQuery 1.10 + the migrate file. I had to upgrade to 1.10 due to a plugin requiring at least that version. It's not a massive deal as I have basically divided my dropdowns into standard, small & big sizes and set the height respectively; but if you want to keep trying I'm happy for you to give it a go!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44516/discussion-between-jsuar-and-brett)

Answer (score 2):

## Best Solution

The real solution for this lies in css,you have to specify max-height and height:auto for SelectBox menu so that jScrollPane works correctly.
All the above solutions needs you to Reinitialize and Destroy scrollpane every time you open drop menu or set fixed height of menu() in onOpen method, but what if menu options are less, you will see blank space in menu.
Below is the ideal solution that requires jScrollPane to initialize just once and no Reinitialize is needed.
(Its a clean and optimal code)

### CSS

/* This class on ul is must for jscrollpane to work correctly, else its height will keep on reducing */

```
.sbOptions{
max-height:200px !important;
height:auto !important;
}
```

### Js

```
$(".pretty_sb").selectbox();
$('.sbOptions').jScrollPane();
```

Tested this solution in FF/Chrome/IE

Answer (score 1):

### Tested and working!

I discovered that there is a bug with `jquery.jscrollpane.js` plugin due to the following reasons:

### First reason:

When doing the following...

```
$(function(){

   $('.pretty_sb').selectbox();
   $('.sbOptions').jScrollPane();

});
```

First line `(..).selectbox()` will customize the html `select` and create the following in `DOM`:

`<ul id="sbOptions_82218379" class="sbOptions" style="display: none; (..)>`

Then second line `(..).jScrollPane()` will create the following children element inside `ul` tag in the middle of script execution:

`<div class="jspContainer" style="width: 155px; height: 454px;">`

And also the following children element inside `jspContainer`:

`<div class="jspPane" style="padding: 5px 0px 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 155px;">(..)</div>`

***At this point `jspPane` element contains the elements of the html `select` at first sight.***

To finally try to get the `scrollHeight` *(friendly known as `height`)* of `jspPane` element in order to create the scrollbar. Seems that everything will work but ***NOT.***

### What's wrong?

Doing some debugging to the `unminified` version of `jquery.jscrollpane.js` plugin *(obtained from the official site at: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js)*

You will see that on `line 177`, the code is trying to get the `scrollHeight` of the `pane` by using simple `javascript` like this:

`contentHeight = pane[0].scrollHeight;`

This will be used in future for creating the `scrollbar` but when trying to get this `CSS` property of a `display: none` parent element this will result in `0`.

So, at `line 182` the script will determine that the area is not scrollable `(isScrollableV = false)` and the scrollbar will not appear due to this.

If you don't want to believe. Try getting the `scrollHeight` by yourself *(I made a short example, just `comment` or `uncomment` the `display: none;` property of the child `div` at `CSS` side: http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/3Ycp7/).*

### Second reason:

This is really funny but check `line 112` of `jquery.jscrollpane.js` plugin, you will see the following comment:

```
// TODO: Deal with where width/ height is 0 as it probably means the element is hidden and we should 
// come back to it later and check once it is unhidden...
```

It seems that the author is not handling when an element is `hidden` or not, so it will return `0` for the `height` or `width` making the area not scrollable ***(as first reason description)***.

### But, why this code snippet works?

```
$('.pretty_sb').selectbox({
    onOpen: function (inst) {
        $('.sbOptions').jScrollPane();
    }
});
```

Because when opening the `combobox`, the content is not `hidden` anymore *(`onOpen` listener makes the trick, you can check the `DOM` and look that `display: none` from `ul` tag is gone)* 
and that allows the `jquery.jscrollpane.js` plugin to get what it wants and further add another `CSS` class (`jspScrollable`) to the `ul` element that means that the area is scrollable
and everything will work fine with the new scrollbar.

### Solution:

- I really ***DON'T*** recommend this solution but maybe you can edit the `unminified` version of  `jquery.jscrollpane.js` plugin just for yourself. But you will be responsible of author license infringement and others *(just saying please don't be rude with me people)*. This way you will invoke just `$(selector).jScrollPane();` and that's all.
- Do what the author `comment` said and evaluate if the element is `hidden` or not but this will be really hard to accomplish for your case because `ul` tag will be `hidden` if the `combobox` is *"closed"* and an `event` listener will be needed *(similar to your last approach to get this working)*.
- I think ***the solution that fits your requirement*** is to continue using your last approach *(the one using the `onOpen` listener with some "corrections" like I will put it later/below)*. But I don't like it at all because you are repeating the `(..).jScrollPane()` action again and again per `click` done. Also, I think that there is no other way to solve this.

**Live Demo:** *http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/8VX4d/33/*

*jQuery code:*

```
/* Define a default global variable with some value for scrollable area height. */
var DEFAULT_SBHEIGHT = 150;

$(function(){

    $('.cat_list').jScrollPane();

    $('.pretty_sb').selectbox({
        onOpen: function (inst) {
            $('.sbOptions')
            .height(DEFAULT_SBHEIGHT)
            .jScrollPane();
        }
    });

});
```

---

*Just to know, there are many possible cases of "script execution" but I just tried to analyze in deep this situation.*

*Hope this helps.*

Comment: I commend you providing a thorough answer, but I think it's a little overkill for the final solution. Especially considering it's the same solution I posted 30 minutes prior to your submission.

Comment: Yes, they look very similar but took me a lot of time to prepare that answer :-) I don't think it's overkill if someone else will learn something. My point of view wasn't to show just the "answer" or possible solution, I also wanted the OP to know what was happening (as he requested also) because if he just follows a code snippet he won't be able to answer himself why he can't do this: `$('.sbOptions').jScrollPane();` and got things working.

Comment: Thanks for the great insightful response. The last option may work but setting a height is not something I wanted to do as it will be applied to many different fields, some dynamic; but I will give your other solutions a look through - but my JS knowledge isn't that great. :(